# Strategy to get the center of mass of a drawer a distance $D$ from its starting position considering a maximum push force and friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A drawer lyes on a rough horizontal surface, as shown in the figure (seen from above).

[image]

The mass of the drawer is $M = 150kg$, its length is $L$ and the coefficient of friction between the surface and the drawer is $u = 0.5$. A man wants to move the center of mass of the drawer a distance $D$ from the starting location but can only apply a maximum push-force of 350$N$. Assuming the drawer is an ideal rigid body, how should the man proceed?

I can't wrap my head around this problem. The horizontal force need to counter the maximum frictional force is larger than $350N$ and net torque would only make the object rotate about its center of mass, thus leaving the latter's position unchanged...

Comment: Why do you assume the object will rotate about its centre of mass ? It will rotate about the point where the net torque of friction and the pushing force is zero.

Comment: I guess because the sum of all external forces must be zero (the frictional force will always counter the pushing force) therefore the acceleration of the center of mass must be zero too. At this point I'm stuck though as the COM must move!

Comment: @LorenzoCatani Cleary, the man cannot apply a force at the COM to move the drawer since the maximum static friction force at that point is 735N. However, I believe as you move away from the COM it requires less force to overcome static friction. Experimenting with a weighted box on a wood floor, it seems to require less force to get the box to begin sliding when you apply the force near the edge of the box than if you apply the force at the COM. The result is translation + rotation, but rotation is not about the COM. The lower the friction the closer it is